# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

Tags: python

Здраствуйте! Я столкнулся с следующей проблемой:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)`.

Возможно это связано с тем, что я пытаюсь взаимодействовать одно слово("test") и всё работает, а если несколько'('test', 'test')' то выдаёт ту самую ошибку. Как это можно исправить?

Вот код:

```
with open(f"inventory/file.json", "r") as write_file:
        data = json.load(write_file)
#data["item"] - допустим внутри значение test
#data["amount"] - допустим внутри значение 2
invItem = data["item"]
invAmount = data["amount"]

items_str = '\n'.join(f'{ii} x{ia}' for (ii,), ia in zip(invItem, invAmount))
print(items_str)
```

```
#inventory/file.json
{"item": [["\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442"], ["\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0440"], ["\u0422\u0435\u0441", "\u0430", "\u0442\u0430"]], "amount": [1, 2]}
#Последнее вызывает ошибку
```

Comment: Что у вас в `invItem`, `invAmount`? Добавьте в вопрос все данные

Comment: @CrazyElf дополнил текст

Comment: Непонятно всё-равно - где у вас `('test', 'test')`?

Comment: Вот тут `for (ii,), ia in zip(invItem, invAmount)` функция zip возвращает данные попарно, второе значение попадает в ia, первое пытается распаковаться как кортеж из одного элемента в ii. Если на самом деле кортеж больше чем из одного элемента, то будет падать с указанной ошибкой. Если остальные элементы нужно проигнорировать, пишите `for (ii, *_), ia in zip(invItem, invAmount)`

Comment: А вообще, приведите в вопросе именно те данные, на которых возникает ошибка, чтобы нам не угадывать, что у вас на самом деле. На приведенном пример file.json ошибка не возникает.

Comment: @insolor вставил данные

Comment: И на этих данных ошибка не вылетает

Comment: @FiolDoll ошибку не выдает: https://replit.com/@insolor/SilverSpecificDrivers#main.py